# Ponegap command line is not building for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

We got a small project in html/js and We want to make a native app just to get the nice icon right on my device.

I have tried to [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) and it works just like I expected. But now I want to build by command line because I don't really want to create a zip file and upload it manualy every time.

For android it's works like a boss. I use the command :

```
phonegap remote build android
```

But I when try it with ios, the build never end. the console output :

```
[phonegap] compressing the app...
[phonegap] uploading the app...
[phonegap] building the app...
```

Just to make sure I was not just too impatient I wait for 2 hours for it.

Any suggestion or do you need more information to resolve my problem?

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns  = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap  = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id         = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode="10" 
    version    = "1.0.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:platform name="winphone" />

    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <description>
        My super app
    </description>

    <access origin="*" />

    <icon src="icons/Icon.png"/>

    <icon src="icons/ios/Icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/Icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/Icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

    <icon src="icons/android/36.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android/48.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android/72.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android/96.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="icons/windows-phone/Icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="icons/windows-phone/Background.png" />

    <gap:splash src="screen/Screen.png" />

    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="screen/android/ldpi.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="screen/android/mdpi.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="screen/android/hdpi.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="screen/android/xhdpi.png" />

    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />

    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="screen/ios/Default.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="screen/ios/Default@2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1004" src="screen/ios/Default-ipad" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2008" src="screen/ios/Default-ipad@2x.png" width="1536" />

    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="screen/windows-phone/Default.png" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `phonegap local build android`?

Comment: In fack the android version work fine in remote and local, it's the ios the problem. I can build the ios version on a Mac with `phonegap local build ios` but We don't really want to manage the creation of the ipa file with xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the app and create a new one with phonegap create resolve the problem.